# LTspice: reverse biased diode fails in ac analysis

Tags: diodes, ltspice, modeling

I want to read out the diode saturation current with ac analysis. In this example, 100uA. Hence I bias the diode at -1V where the diode current is effectively the saturation current (*-1). It works with `.op` analysis but fails with `.ac` analysis: As can be seen, the result is basically zero:

[image]

(It does not work with `I(D2)` either).

WHY?

PS: This is just a simplified test which is part of a larger simulation in which I need to sweep over different Id values. Since I cannot parameterize this, I create multiple `.model` statements with nunmerical values and sweep over them. However, in order to plot versus the actual `Is` values (as opposed to the numerical IDs of the model) I need to read out the saturation current for each step.

**EDIT:** I think I know why: The Is I am looking for is the large signal value. It gets discarded in the small signal ac-analysis. Then the question is: How can I obain "Is" of a diode from an ac-analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conducting an `.AC` analysis, so you can't treat the results as if they were in `.TRAN`. In `.TRAN`, you see the direct effect of the applied voltage. In `.AC`, despite you applying a DC voltage, the result is the *magnitude* and *phase* of the applied `AC 1` voltage.

What happens is the DC `.op` point is calculated (since this is a nonlinear element) based on the DC value, here `1 V`. The diode is linearized for a small signal analysis. Then a `1 V` *complex* signal is applied and read at node `out`, and the magnitude of it would be based on the resistive divider formed by the *linearized resistance* of the diode. Also, the default parameter for `Rs` is zero, which you haven't set.

---

Seeing you modified the question, I don't think it's possible, since the `.AC` analysis tries to linearize all the models, there is no dynamic value, and the signal is a complex signal.

Answer (score 0):

The diode model you have is ideal, to make it more realistic [add parameters](http://www.ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm). The ideal model is strictly a PN junction, with no capacitance. If you want to supply capacitance then try adding Cjo (with an appropriate value for a diode you are trying to model).

```
.model Test D(Is=100e-6 N=1.06 Cjo=1e-9)
```

Remember that spice models are far from the real world, wires superconduct, capacitors and inductors are ideal with no high frequency parasitics and there is no global capacitance (the real world is capacitively connected to everything.

Another note: the leads on any diode with also have nH of inductance, so will the traces on the PCB.

Comment: Using any other parameters from the "real" model makes LTspice to discard the ideal model. If any of the ideal parameters is used in addition to the real ones, the diode is treated as ideal, as the "good book" says: "*This idealized model is used if any of Ron, Roff, Vfwd, Vrev or Rrev is specified in the model*". OP has not specified any of these, so even if only `Is` is specified, the model is no longer ideal.

Comment: But I purposefully do **not** want Cj0 (for now). (I wrote WHY I need to read out Id...it's just a hack to get Is for other computations since LTspice doesn't allow me to sweep over Is). And, ac should linearize at the DC operating point. So when my operating point is At Vdiode=-1 when an ac analysis with ac=1 should give me the current at this point. Besides, adding Cjo doesn't help. At low frequencies, the current is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (alhough I am not sure if this is the right way to do it):

As I have indicated in my own question, the ac analysis is a small signal analysis. Hence it discards the large signal information (DC bias point).

The proper thing to do seems to use the DC voltage 0V as bias voltage because then, spice linearizes 1/Req = dI/dV = Is/Vth.

Now Req = Vac/Iac. Vac=1 and Iac is the result of the simulation. Hence Is=Vth * Iac / Vac=Vth * Iac.